# displayNewMessageForm does not work when used inside Outlook reply

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in that is available on compose and read mode. If user goes through the compose add-in , at the end, some content created by user gets added to the email body. You can only see the compose add-in when you click 'NEW'.

On Read scenario, I have 3 options on my add-in commands dropdown - New, Reply, ReplyAll. User goes through the add-in, same as Compose mode, but at the end I use **displayNewMessageForm, displayReplyForm** and **displayReplyAllForm** to create a new email depending on action chosen.

So far it works fine. Here comes the problem:

When user opens an email and uses Outlook's **reply/replyall/forward** actions, my add-in shows up on the new window. (Arrow just shows my add-in icon)
[image]
 Now, user clicks the add-in completes the necessary steps and at the end I use displayNewMessageForm,displayReplyForm and displayReplyAllForm again to create a new email. But at this point, above API calls are failing.

Error Message: Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm is not a function.
Although I don't think it is code related, here is the code for those API calls.

**Formdata** and **parameters** are properly formed and it works fine on the read mode.

```
 if (selectedEmailType == 'New' || selectedEmailType == 'NewEmail') {
                                                Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(parameters);
                                        }
                                        if (selectedEmailType == 'ReplyEmail') {
                                                Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm(
                                                        formdata,
                                                        function(asyncResult) {
                                                                console.log(asyncResult.value);
                                                                Office.context.ui.closeContainer();
                                                        }
                                                );
                                        } else if ((selectedEmailType == 'ReplyAllEmail')) {
                                                Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm(
                                                        formdata,
                                                        function(asyncResult) {
                                                                console.log(asyncResult.value);
                                                                Office.context.ui.closeContainer();
                                                        }
                                                );
                                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to use displayReplyForm and the other mentioned APIs while an add-in is running while composing an email. These APIs can only be used in Read Mode and will not be available in Compose Mode. You can [find the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#displayreplyformformdata-callback). The "Applicable Outlook Mode" for these API's is "Read".